# Google Tag Manager & Oracle APEX : Track close dialog

Tags: oracle, google-analytics, modal-dialog, google-tag-manager

I've implemented Google Analytics in a ORACLE APEX application.
I would like to know how to track the event 'closing a modal dialog / press close button' in Google Analytics.

I've tried the following with Google Tag Manager:

**Tag**
[image]
I've created a tag, as an event type. Which contains a trigger which will trigger the tag when the clicked element matches .ui-dialog-titlebar-close.

**Trigger**
[image]

**The close button HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" title="Close">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
</button>
```

When I change the CSS matches in the trigger with a Next(volgende) or cancel(annuleren) button, the tag get activated on click and the event can be viewed in Google Analytics Events:
[image]

I hope some one can help me out!

**Edit**

> Changed the CSS ui-dialog-titlebar-close mention to
>   .ui-dialog-titlebar-close, was missing a dot. But that didn't solved
>   my problem. Still can't see the close action in events.

Comment: css Selector requires a actual css selector you missed the class, the .(dot), try `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close`

Comment: @ztadic91 That doesn't actually fix my problem, that's to bad.. Any other solutions? :)

Comment: can you provide a link to the site where the html is located?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you the url to the site, it's a private application which cannot be accessed from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be too long to post as a comment, so i'll add a possible answer here.
Try with this selector.

```
.ui-button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close,.ui-button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick,.ui-button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-button-text
```

This is a selector for the button and the two spans elements inside.

Comment: @Elvira please mark the question as answered if it solved your problem

Comment: Done, I've accidently clicked the arrow above istead of the answer acception. Thanks again! I'm glad it works now.